# Form reset Stack overflow at line IE 10, 8

Tags: javascript, html, forms, stack-overflow, reset

i am using a form like below and getting error in IE `Stack overflow at line: 367`

```
<form id="appointmentForm" onreset="resetAppointmentForm()" action="" method="post" novalidate class="appointmentForm">
```

In above form tag `onreset="resetAppointmentForm()` attribute is causing error. removing this from markup would solve the error but did not reset form.

```
function resetAppointmentForm() {
    document.forms['appointmentForm'].reset();
    $('.appointmentForm .alert').remove();
}
```

Comment: Remove `document.forms['appointmentForm'].reset();` will fix it.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 thanks alot, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `form` tag you have this:

```
onreset="resetAppointmentForm()"
```

And in that function you have this:

```
document.forms['appointmentForm'].reset();
```

So... Triggering a form reset triggers a form reset.  That's an infinite recursion.  Thus, a stack overflow error.

Remove that line from within the function.  There's no need for an event handler to trigger itself.